# How to return date type using CASE WHERE or WHEN Clauses

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  WITH t_summary AS (
            SELECT empid, result, t_date
                ,   SUM(CASE WHEN t_date >= sysdate-5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_01 
                ,   SUM(CASE WHEN t_date >= sysdate-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_02   
                ,   SUM(CASE WHEN t_date < sysdate-15 AND t_date >= sysdate-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_03
              FROM employees
             WHERE result IN ('TRUE')
               AND t_date >= sysdate-30
             GROUP BY empid, result, t_date  
    )  
    SELECT empid, result, t_date
      FROM t_summary
    
    /* I should have a logic to define t_date (date type) associated with test_01 and test_03 at least.
    
        if test_01 > 0 AND test_02 = 0, MAX(test_01.t_date)
        else if test_01 > 0 AND test_03 > 0, MIN(test_03.t_date)
    
    */
    
      WHERE t_date = (CASE WHEN test_01 > 0 AND test_02=0 THEN test_01.t_date
    ...
                                     ELSE NULL
                                     END)
    ;
```

I couldn't complete the work yet. How can I assign the date along with test_01, test_02 and test_03?

Comment: What?   Sorry, you need to be more clear.  show all table DDL, sample data, expected outputs

Answer (score 1):

This will never match any rows.

---

In the `WITH` clause, you have the filter:

```sql
WHERE t_date >= sysdate-30
```

Then in the `SELECT` you have:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN t_date >= sysdate-30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS test_02
```

Since the `WHERE` clause will filter out any rows there `t_date < SYSDATE-30` then the `CASE` expression will always be true then you are effectively using:

```sql
SUM(1) AS test_02
```

Which will always give you a positive value.

Finally, in the outer query, you have:

```sql
WHERE t_date = (CASE
                WHEN test_01 > 0 AND test_02=0
                THEN test_01.t_date
                ELSE NULL
                END)
```

Since, there must be one matching row for a group to exist then `test_02` must be non-zero so the `CASE` expression will never match that `WHEN` clause and you are filtering for `WHERE t_date = NULL` and since `NULL` is never equal to anything then your query will never match a row.

*(Ignoring the fact that `test_01.t_date` is invalid syntax as you do not declare a table or an table alias with the identifier `test_01`.)*